# unity 3D character rotation problem. character spinning around in a big circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is when the rotation is starting in the 1st photo, when I press the WASD button once, it comes to the position in the 2nd photo.character spinning around in a big circle .[1.Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liYmt.png)
[2. Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNLhg.png)

```
[SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] float rotationSpeed = 500f;

    Quaternion targetRotation;

    CameraController cameraController;

    private void Update()
    {

        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        float moveAmount = Mathf.Abs(h) + Mathf.Abs(v);

        var moveInput = (new Vector3(h,0,v)).normalized;

        var moveDir = cameraController.PlanarRotation * moveInput;

        if(moveAmount > 0)
        {
            transform.position += moveDir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDir);
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        cameraController =  Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraController>();
    }
```

when i tried to find out where the problem was i realized that the problem is in `Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDir)`

Comment: There's not enough info to figure out what's wrong, but I'll try to give you a net instead of the fish. Try using the `Debug.DrawLine(start, end, color)` to visualize your vector calculations right in the Scene View, this would help you to find the mistake in math or logic when dealing with space vectors.